# Move a certain distance (geometry_msg:Twist)

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently this is the code that I have, and I am able to get the robot moving by editing the linear x or angular z values (speed).

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "move_pub");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher movement_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("mobile_base/commands/velocity",1); 
ros::Rate rate(10);

while (ros::ok()) 
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist move;
    //velocity controls
    move.linear.x = -0.1; //speed value m/s
    move.angular.z = 0;
    movement_pub.publish(move);

    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}
return 0;
}
```

Is there a time control in ROS? Whereby I can do something like while time <= 5s, publish linear x velocity of 0.2m/s. Thus, covering 1 meter. I am new to ROS and it is my first week into it. Im working on the TurtleBot 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205058/move-a-certain-distance-(geometry_msg:twist)/) by [dylankc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21875/dylankc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-16**:
Also see [robot pose slightly off when publishing to /cmd_vel](http://answers.ros.org/question/204973/robot-pose-slightly-off-when-publishing-to-cmd_vel/) for some discussion on the feasibility of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is `ros::Time` and `ros::Duration`, which can be used in an intuitive way. `ros::Time::now()` gives you the current time.
You probably want something like:

```
ros::Time start = ros::Time::now()
while(ros::Time::now() - start < ros::Duration(5.0))
    ...
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dylankc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21875/dylankc/) on 2015-03-16**:
Thank you dornhege for teaching me about the ros::Time & ros::Duration function. However, i've taken a look at "http://answers.ros.org/question/204973/robot-pose-slightly-off-when-publishing-to-cmd_vel/" and realized that my method is prone to inaccuracy!

I'll try publishing to /odom.

**Comment by [dylankc](https://answers.ros.org/users/21875/dylankc/) on 2015-03-16**:
I appreciate your help very much. Thank you